# Refresh gridview data in a page present in the server

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have created a asp.net webpage which contains a gridview.I bound the gridview to an access database through the steps the gridview control provides when drag dropped from the toolbox(not from the code). This page is actually in the server. When i do an updation in the client(in another webpage)(like:add or delete a record in the database)the gridview does not reflect the changes,though the values in the database are changed. Only when i refresh in the server the change is seen in the client side. plz help.

Comment: maybe the page is getting cached.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [asp.net ajax timer](http://ajax.net-tutorials.com/controls/timer-control/) control to refresh the page / part of page periodically. The following example shows you can update server time every 5 second. Similarly you will update the `GridView`.

*HTML*

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" />
    <asp:Timer runat="server" id="UpdateTimer" interval="5000" ontick="UpdateTimer_Tick" />
    <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" id="TimedPanel" updatemode="Conditional">
        <Triggers>
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger controlid="UpdateTimer" eventname="Tick" />
        </Triggers>
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:Label runat="server" id="DateStampLabel" />
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

*Code behind*

```
protected void UpdateTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DateStampLabel.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString();
}
```

Comment: thanq.,But to update the gridview using GridView1.DataBind(); is enough?

Comment: You will have to assign data to datasource as well.

Comment: protected void UpdateTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        GridView1.DataSourceID = AccessDataSource1;
         GridView1.DataBind(); when i give like this i get an error " Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.AccessDataSource' to 'string'"
Line 58:     }

Comment: GridView1.DataSourceID = "AccessDataSource1";
        GridView1.DataBind(); i tried this still its not working..there is no updation

Answer (score 1):

The best way to achieve this is by using **SignalR**.

The following tutorial will give you an Idea on how to implement Server Broadcasting.

Click [here](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/getting-started/tutorial-server-broadcast-with-aspnet-signalr) for an example.

Answer (score 0):

thank you all.The below code worked for me:

aspx page:

```
<asp:Panel ID="Panel2" runat="server" Height="146px" Style="z-index: 100; left: 382px;
        position: absolute; top: 247px" Visible="true" Width="235px">
         <asp:Label ID="deptlabel" runat="server" 
    style="z-index: 1; left: 0px; top: 33px; position: absolute" Text="Label" 
    Visible="False"></asp:Label>
        <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" />
 <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
```

```
         <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
            DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" Style="z-index: 100; left: -146px;
            position: absolute; top: 216px; height: 374px; width: 1024px;" AllowSorting="True" 
             CellPadding="3" AllowPaging="True" BackColor="#DEBA84" BorderColor="#DEBA84" 
             BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" CellSpacing="2">
            <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Delete">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="chkDelete" runat="server" />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="bid" HeaderText="bid" 
                    SortExpression="bid" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="did" HeaderText="did" SortExpression="did" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="bname" HeaderText="bnme" 
                    SortExpression="bname" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="author" HeaderText="athr" 
                    SortExpression="author" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="price" HeaderText="cost" 
                    SortExpression="price" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="edition" HeaderText="editn" 
                    SortExpression="edition" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="category" HeaderText="ctgry" 
                    SortExpression="category" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="publisher" HeaderText="publsr" 
                    SortExpression="publisher" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="status" HeaderText="stat" 
                    SortExpression="status" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="acpr" HeaderText="acpr" SortExpression="acpr" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="volume" HeaderText="vol" 
                    SortExpression="volume" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="ref" HeaderText="ref" SortExpression="ref" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="pages" HeaderText="pgs" SortExpression="pages" />
            </Columns>
            <RowStyle BackColor="#FFF7E7" ForeColor="#8C4510" />
            <FooterStyle BackColor="#F7DFB5" ForeColor="#8C4510" />
            <PagerStyle ForeColor="#8C4510" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
            <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#738A9C" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
            <HeaderStyle BackColor="#A55129" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        </asp:GridView>

         </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
    &nbsp;<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
            ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:con %>" 
              SelectCommand="SELECT DISTINCT * FROM [books] WHERE ([bid] LIKE '%' + @bid + '%')">
         <SelectParameters>
             <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="deptlabel" Name="bid" PropertyName="Text" 
                 Type="String" />
         </SelectParameters>  </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

```
        &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;
</asp:Panel>
<asp:Label ID="Label9" runat="server" Font-Size="XX-Large" ForeColor="#C04000" Style="z-index: 102;
    left: 492px; position: absolute; top: 256px; width: 678px;" 
    Text="BOOKS REMOVE"></asp:Label>
```

default.aspx.cs:

protected void Timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

```
    GridView1.DataBind();

}
```